# Using a json object out of ajax succes function (Using angular.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I am using an API to search for songs but I just wanted to simply show 1 song from the array in my html file by using an expression in angular.js. Now I have bumped into some problems because I want to use my JSON object out of the AJAX call and in the controller.

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('songSelector', []);
    app.controller('playedTracksCtrl', function() {
        // this.songs = jsonObjectPlayedTracks;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.q-music.be/1.2/tracks/plays?limit=20", 
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            jsonp: "callback", 
            success: function(jsonObject){
                //console.log(jsonObject); 
                //console.log(jsonObject["played_tracks"][0]);

                var jsonObjectPlayedTracks = jsonObject["played_tracks"];
                console.log(jsonObjectPlayedTracks);
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="songSelector">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 class="text-center">Vind info over de laatste 50 liedjes</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center"> - vul in - </h2>
        </header>
        <div class="list-group" ng-controller="playedTracksCtrl as overzicht">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <h3>{{overzicht.songs[0].title}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>  {{"Hello, Angular!"}}  </p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the returned JSON?

Comment: If you are using angular, use `$http` or `$resource` instead of jQuery. Angular is a complete framework with support for almost all things you need. jQuery is just DOM manipulation, and useful functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make ajax calls, you need to use `$http` or `$resource`:

```
(function() {

     var app = angular.module('songSelector', []);

     app.controller('playedTracksCtrl', ['songService', playedTraksCtrl]);
     app.service('songService', ['$http', songService])

     function playedTraksCtrl(songService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.songs = {};

        songService.getPlays().then(function (data) {
          vm.songs = data;
        });
      }

      function songService($http){
        var service = {
          getPlays: getPlays
        };
        return service;

        function getPlays(){
          return $http.get('http://api.q-music.be/1.2/tracks/plays?limit=20')
          .then(function (data) {
            return data.data;
          }).catch(function (message) {
            console.log(message)
          });
        }
      }
})();
```

Angular sorts out the JSON for you.

I'll break it down:

```
function songService($http){
    var service = {
        getPlays: getPlays
    };
    return service;
}
```

This returns you an object:

```
{
    getPlays: function () {}
}
```

The function up there is the one we created after the `return service;`:

```
function getPlays(){
    return $http.get('http://api.q-music.be/1.2/tracks/plays?limit=20')
            .then(function (data) {
                return data.data;
            }).catch(function (message) {
                console.log(message)
            });
}
```

As you can see this function immediately returns the result of another function: `$http.get()`. The result is a `Promise`. A `Promise` says, when the result comes back fire a function off.

We need to tell that `Promise` what we want to do both in the service AND the controller. So in the service:

```
.then(function (data) {
    return data.data;
}).catch(function (message) {
    console.log(message)
});
```

the `.then()` basically says, when the `Promise` resolves `then` fire this function. The function has a parameter (or many actually but I only care about data most of the time). Data has lots of properties on it, and the one we're interested, the result of your API is `data`. So what we do is just return that out.

This `Promise` chains so then in the controller, we can call another `.then()`. This is fired when the one in service has finished calling.

```
songService.getPlays().then(function (data) {
    vm.songs = data;
});
```

We know by this point, that the data is just the JSON object as a JS object that we can use. So we just assign it to the `vm.songs` property.

**Remember**

A `Promise` is there because the call is Asynchronous, so if you see a blank space it will be because the call hasn't finished resolving. When it does, it will call that `then()` function.